# Login screen not appearing post boot

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, login-screen

Once we boot the OS, I can see the **Windows Logo**. After that it should load the **Logon screen to click on login**. But unfortunately, a **blank screen** appears with a Cursor. I can move around the cursor, but nothing happens.

I tried all the possible shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> still nothing happens.

I have **removed the RAM** and **re-installed it again**, but still the same issue.
Tried booting with safe mode, the drivers will load, but nothing happens, the computer is getting rebooted again.

Comment: https://windowsforum.com/threads/login-screen-not-appearing.57980/